# Broken 302 redirection for product subcategory (Woocommerce, Apache)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, apache

I have problem with 302 redirections for subcategory pages. The site combine new URL with old. For example old url was:

```
domain.pl/product-category/she/leggins/
```

and I want to redirec it to

```
domain.pl/c/womens-clothing/natural-leggins/
```

I've written redirection in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 302 /product-category/she/leggins /c/womens-clothing/natural-leggins/
```

And it doesn't work for subcategory. Site try to mix new address with old subcategory and i get:

*domain.pl/c/womens-clothing/**leggins**/*

There should be "**natural-leggins**" on ending, not "leggins".

Redirections for category work fine. There is limit for length or amount of /segments/?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :) Redirections for categories should be after subcategories. For example:

```
Redirect 302 /product-category/she/leggins/ /c/womens-clothing/natural-leggins/
Redirect 302 /product-category/she/t-shirts/ /c/womens-clothing/natural-t-shirts/
Redirect 302 /product-category/she/ /c/womens-clothing/
```